# Usage of ''both"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

1. Both the control laws demand high magnitude of acceleration at the end.
2. Both the control laws demand high magnitudes of acceleration at the end.
3. At the end phase, acceleration demand of both the guidance laws shoots up.
4. At the end phase, acceleration demands of both the guidance laws shoot up.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score -1):

I had not seen "both" after "of"  so I would say that the last two are wrong.

The majority of the time, I had seen the word "Both" in order to omit the noun.

For example: John and Heather? Both are coming to the wedding.

However, the word "Both" can be used as an adjective. As result of it, (S1) and (S2) are right but you have to change the order like this: 
"The both control laws demand high magnitude of acceleration at the end."

Comment: No, absolutely not. There's nothing wrong with _both_ occurring after _of_, but your ‘corrected’ version is ***completely ungrammatical***. No native speaker of English would ever say that. _Both_ is **never** an adjective; it is a [_predeterminer_](http://i.word.com/idictionary/predeterminer) or a pronoun.